# Mimic tagged unions in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I've been looking at GraphQL for use in a project I'm working on. For the project, we've defined the overall data structure using Haskell data types (for illustrative purposes). This contains types such as this:

```
data Requirement
  = Purchased PurchaseId
  | Attained Outcome Real
  | Invited
```

So, a requirement for something might be that the user has *bought* a certain item, *attained* a certain score, or been invited.

From reading the docs, I'd guess that a `union` is what I'd want to express the *type* of requirement, but is there an elegant way to deal with the differences in **content** for each member of the union?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No worries, I solved it myself! [Interfaces](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) are exactly what I need.

Example:

```
interface Requirement {
    id: ID!
}

type Purchased implements Requirement {
    id: ID!
    mustHavePurchased: ID!
}

# etc...
```

Comment: That's not a tagged union without a discriminator field.
Discriminator fields can be implemented with enums, literal types etc. but GraphQL doesn't support referring to specific enum values as types and going with literal types is too verbose.
Unless you are using `__typename` for discrimination.